# How to set Eclipse embedded Tomcat's appBase attribute?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, hostname, eclipse-wtp

I'm maintaining a webapp in java using Eclipse (4.8) and something quite strange happened when I added my tomcat server and ran my application in it : every file was deployed in wtpwebapps folder (${Workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wtp.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps), but the appBase was set to webapps.

It took me quite some time to realise that Tomcat was redirecting http requests to (empty) webapps folder rather than wtpwebapps.
Of course, I changed the setting through Eclipse Tomcat instance's server.xml file and everything then went fine :

```xml
<host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
<!-- some context & settings -->
</host>
```

I just changed to "appBase" attribute to "wtpwebapps"

I was just wondering if I missed some point here.

I deleted and re-add the tomcat server several times, but appBase attribute is set to webapps rather than wtpwebapps and I have to change the value manually in server.xml each time.
Is there a way in Eclipse to explicitely set the appbase for one Eclipse embedded Tomcat instance ?

What could make eclipse set by default webapps folder to appBase attribute each time I add a new server ?

Comment: What versions of Tomcat and Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse version : 4.11.0; Tomcat version : 8.5.39